# 'Use unfiltered layer' option in QGIS query builder

Tags: qgis, filter

When you create a filter, a 'use unfiltered layer' option is displayed in the query builder window. I expected this option to allow the user to toggle between the filtered and unfiltered layer. It doesn't seem to work like that as nothing seems to happen when I select it. Have I missed something?

qGIS 3.14.16-Pi Windows 10 64bits

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This setting is used for the `value` box, which is useful ONLY within the query builder interface.

For example select the `osm_id` field click on the `sample` or `all`, you will get, well, all results.

Set a filter to be `osm_id < 1000000`. Click on `sample` or `all`, you will get ONLY results with an osm_id less than 1 000 000.

Check the `use unfiltered layer` box, click on `sample` or `all`, you will get all results, including osm_id greater than 1 000 000.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand better how the query builder interface works.